# LDAP doesn't return a specifi sAMAccountName unless I explicitly search for it

Tags: ldap, ldapsearch

i.e. I have a username - tonysmith, and when I run the query for all accounts in the DC, tonysmith isn't returned unless I specifically query for sAMAccountName=tonysmith. What gives?

Comment: maybe you hit the limit of the results per query, but as you show nothing, it's impossible to tell :-)

Comment: Post your query in your question.

Comment: @natxoasenjo i did hit the 1000 result limit in my query, so further refining my ldap query solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to hitting the 1000 result query limit.